# Is Ham($S^2$) homeomorphic to SO(3)?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

Is it true that Ham($S^2$,\omega), the group of Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms of the sphere $S^2$ with its standard symplectic structure $\omega$, is homeomorphic to SO(3)?

Comment: This old question bumped into my notifications. So I decided to modify it a bit for clarity, since its author had disappeared.

Answer (score 6):

The correct statement is:

> **Claim.** The group $Ham(S^2)=Ham(S^2,\omega)$ of Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms of the $2$-sphere $S^2$ (endowed with the standard symplectic structure $\omega$) is homotopy equivalent to the group of rotations $SO(3)$.

Notice that, while $SO(3)$ is a finite-dimensional Lie group, the group $Ham(S^2)$ (i.e. the time-$1$ maps of Hamiltonian flows) is an infinite dimensional topological manifold with the $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ topology, i.e. that of "uniform convergence of all derivatives".

Probably you can reconstruct a complete proof of the above claim by looking at the details in the following references (which I just found online by a google search):

1. In general, there are inclusions
   $$Ham(M,\omega)\subseteq Symp_0(M,\omega)\subseteq Symp(M,\omega)\subseteq Diff^{+}(M)$$
   with notations as in [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20161011140804/http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Edusa/groupoxfin.pdf) short survey by Dusa McDuff.<sup>1</sup> On page 2 it's stated that, if $H^1(M,\mathbb{R})=0$ (which is the case of $S^2$) then $Ham(M,\omega)=Symp_0(M,\omega)$.
2. In the same survey, on page 3, it's stated that in dimension 2 "Moser's argument" implies that $Symp_0(M,\omega)$ is homotopy equivalent to $Diff^+(M)$.
3. [Theorem (Smale)](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1959-010-04/S0002-9939-1959-0112149-8/S0002-9939-1959-0112149-8.pdf):  The group of orientation preserving diffeomorphisms of $S^2$ deformation-retracts onto $SO(3)$, so it's homotopy equivalent to the latter.

<sup>1</sup>*McDuff, Dusa*, [**A survey of the topological properties of symplectomorphism groups**](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511526398.010), Tillmann, Ulrike (ed.), Topology, geometry and quantum field theory. Proceedings of the 2002 Oxford symposium in honour of the 60th birthday of Graeme Segal, Oxford, UK, June 24–29, 2002. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 0-521-54049-6/pbk). London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series 308, 173-193 (2004). [arXiv:math/0404340](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404340), [ZBL1102.57013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1102.57013), [MR2079375](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2079375).

Comment: I saw that this was bumped - so I replaced [this boken link](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~dusa/groupoxfin.pdf) by a [Wayback Machine snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20161011140804/http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~dusa/groupoxfin.pdf). But since  the paper seems to be available on arXiv, perhaps the Wayback Machine link could be removed completely.